# referencing data folder within a flask application

Tags: jquery, json, flask

For Flask and with the following directory structure, how can I reference the `data/data.json` file from within the `static/js/main.js` file where I am using a `$.getJSON('data/data.json')` statement. I am always getting 404 file not found reply.

`.
├── data
│   └── data.json
├── server.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   └── main.css
│   └── js
│       └── main.js
└── templates
    ├── form.html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can serve the JSON file from Flask route and manipulate the route using AJAX in the template.

Here I have recreated your scenario with same directory structure and got positive result using the mentioned approach.

`server.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for
import os, json   

app = Flask(__name__)
SITE_ROOT = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

json_url = os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, "data", "data.json")
data = json.load(open(json_url))

@app.route('/')
def show_index():
    return render_template("form.html")

@app.route('/data')
def get_data():
    global data    
    return json.dumps(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`form.html` contains jQuery CDN and the main js file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="author" content="Ahmedur Rahman Shovon">
    <title>JSON Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result"></div>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/main.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`main.js` file contains:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('/data',function(data, status, xhr){
        $("#result").html(data["name"]);        
    })  
})
```

The `data.json` contains following dummy JSON data:

```
{
    "name": "pumpkin pie",
    "ingredients": [" large eggs plus 1 yolk", "1 tsp ground cinnamon"],
    "methods": {
        "1": "Pre-heat the oven to 200C/400F/Gas 6",
        "2": "If using a shop bought sweet crust pastry case, use one that is 23cm/9in diameter and 4cm/1.5in deep. If using your own pastry, roll it out and use it to line a 23cm/9in pie plate (not loose bottomed). Bake the pastry case blind for 20 minutes."
    } 
}
```

Output:

[image: json output]

Comment: great. I was trying to access the `data.json` directly in the `js` file. The way you advocated is to make the data available through a route `/data` and then let `$.getJSON` access that route